# How to couple two nets via VPN and access a network printer across the nets?

Tags: printing, vpn

I like to couple two networks via VPN. The remote network has 192.168.55.x and the local network is on the same private network, so also 192.168.55.x

Under Ubunut 18.04.1 I have a working VPN connection from my Laptop 192.168.55.215 to the remote net where I can ping all devices. But as soon as the VPN is up I can no longer ping any device on my net, nor access the networkprinter.

I assume that I have to set a route so that the remote net can access my net (e.g. print from remote on my local network).

I als assume that these setting somehow need to be made on this settings page. The German word "Strecke" would be "route". Unfortunately I got stuck at this point. In case I am correct what would I need to enter to couple the both 192.55.168.x nets? What about the metric field??

Thanks for any hint
Michael

[image]

Comment: They pretty much **have** to be on separate subnets for this to work. VPN's are *typically* routed networks, that is L3 networks. If the network address is the same at both sides, this will break down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because your VPN is setting the default route and routing table such that all traffic goes out over the VPN.  This means your LAN is no longer your LAN; you become part of the VPN 'LAN'.

Think about the term Virtual Private Network.  You're virtually joining a remote, private network, and your computer traffic will originate from there.

If you compare the output `route`, before and after connecting to the VPN, you'll see what I mean.  If `sudo route` isn't available, the same information can be found using `sudo ip route`.

```
sudo route
```

If you take note of the original routing table, you can re-add the routes and gain access to your local LAN (assuming 192.168.1.1 is your router):

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.1
```

You should only need a single route added to gain access to each local network.  Be sure *not* to add any external routes.

---

The VPN is doing this because it's the easiest way to suck in all of your network traffic to 'secure' it and ensure all of your data goes through their servers.  Your computer will want to take the quickest route to any destination, so if you tell it how to do this, by providing a route, you should be able to re-gain access to your LAN while connected to the VPN.

You'll encounter issues if the two subnets are the same and will need to adjust your local LAN, as you have control over that.  Are the subnets the same because you made them the same after trying to solve for previous issues you experienced?  If that is the case, adding the proper `route` would solve your original problem.

If you have zero control over either network, you can **try** adding the route, and specifying the network device.  If it works, it will mean that you only have access to one or the other network as the LAN.  This would be fine if you don't need printers on the VPN LAN, but would be pretty magical and you might experience issues in the future that would be nearly impossible to pinpoint and fix.

Thanks for the interesting details, but I'm confused about you not having control over at least one of the nets.  You could try tricking your computer into using another [CIDR block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), say `/30`, and ensuring that any devices you wish to access on your true LAN are within that block, connect to the VPN, and add the route for the `/30` block to route through your Ethernet card using your local router.

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.55.253/30 via 192.168.55.1 dev eth0
```

Or more simply, just add a single route to the known IP of the Printer

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.55.253 via 192.168.55.1 dev eth0
```

Here, you're telling your computer to put any traffic to this IP/set of IPs over eth0, or your normal networking interface, vs the tunnel (`tun0`) that the VPN has created.

Don't open up your LAN to the VPN.  Teach your computer how to be on both networks at the same time.

Comment: To you question: both nets exist over 20! years and it is just a simple coincidence that they are both on 192.168.55.x A simple change is on neither side possible.
The overall use case is that I'd like to use a local printer out of the remote net which I VPN in. -- Would it be possible to add only local printer, keeping the sub nets the same?

Comment: Kind of.  If you have control over the IPs which are used/given to the devices you wish to access (ie: Laptop, Printer), you could set up a `route` on the Laptop to push traffic to a smaller subnet to your router, which should allow access to the printer from your Laptop.